# Line breaks in "NSString"s returned from PList don't work

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, plist

I've seen this post: [NSString: newline escape in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035567/nsstring-newline-escape-in-plist) but I'd like to know if there's a way to pragmatically render \n line breaks.

I'm currently using:

```
decisionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: (@"%@", [replies objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [replies count])])];
```

Which randomly grabs a String from the `replies` array. The array was loaded from a plist like so:

```
replies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"AdviceList" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

What am I missing? The answer can't be to manually enter line breaks. That's not programming! (Sounds like word processing to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moshe: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to render the text into a UILabel, you have to set the number of lines (`setNumberOfLines:`, `0` means unlimited). Then set the text(`-[UILabel setText:]`) and tell the label to resize itself (`-[UILabel sizeToFit]`). Now the label will break the lines properly to fit within the space.

Good luck.

Comment: Will that follow the "\n" characters, or ignore them still?

Comment: This is not ok if you need to specify the where the line breaks are from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Irrelevant to your original problem, but is still a problem:-

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: (@"%@", etc)];
```

This expression does not perform the action you really want. The extra parenthesis makes that a *comma expression*, where the `@"%@"` will be ignored, and becomes

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: etc];
```

There shouldn't be any parenthesis in the variadic call. Please use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", etc];
```

This can be written more efficiently as `[etc description]`.