# How to put \n into string in plist

Tags: iphone, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString: newline escape in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035567/nsstring-newline-escape-in-plist)

I have a plist with a string, and I want to get line breaks.

Putting \n\n doesn't work.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

already answered here:
[NSString: newline escape in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035567/nsstring-newline-escape-in-plist)