# String formatting issue - new line not printing correctly

Tags: ios

I have a bit of an odd problem. I have been populating a UITextView as follows, and it has been working fine.

```
textView.Text = @"Blah blah blah\nblah blah blah";
```

Now I have moved the string to a plist and I am grabbing the text dynamically from that plist and now the '\n' is actually showing the in the text view but I want it to function as a new line. Any ideas what might be the issue?

I am using a custom method for grabbing the text from the plist like so.

```
+ (NSString*)readValueFromPlist:(NSString*)plistName forKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistName ofType:@"plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return [dict valueForKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a literal `\n` in a plist file won't work.  You have to use 'option + enter' instead when editing the text value.  Or you can unescape the literal `\n` sequence yourself programmatically.

You can find more details here:  [NSString: newline escape in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035567/nsstring-newline-escape-in-plist)