# Plist to string type in ios

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsstring

I am trying to take up data from plist. One row in plist has sentences with "\n" in between to change line when displayed in the view controller. But as I am picking up the plist as an array, on casting that element to string using NSString, it is not getting read as a localized string. there is no line change. the whole text is getting displayed along with '\n' in between. how do i make the '\n' work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that plist files escape backslashes to make sure they will be displayed as typed.  This means that the `\n` you see is stored as `\\n` within the file.  If you are using XML storage, open it in a text editor to see this.

This problem is discussed and multiple solutions suggested in [NSString: newline escape in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2035567/1318452).