# Using \n in stringdict file

Tags: swift, localization

[image: strindict file]

I m using stringdict file for pluralization in iOS. I need to use the \n for the new line but If I use \n in stringdict file it's not showing the text in the new file. How can I use \n for the new line?

Comment: And if you call it, does the new line appear. It's might be just how XCode show a plist file. It's not done for showing more that one line.

Comment: no. It shows \n as text

Comment: Maybe there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035567/nsstring-newline-escape-in-plist

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thanks @Larme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSString: newline escape in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035567/nsstring-newline-escape-in-plist)

Comment: Yes. That's answer my question

Answer (score 3):

- Verified Solution:

The stringsdict file allows you to jump to a new line using the key combination (option + enter)